# How to write getParent correctly with typescript

Tags: typescript, mobx, mobx-state-tree

So I have two models: `RootStore` and `ProjectsModel`:

```
const RootStore = types
  .model({
    user: types.maybeNull(User),
    projects: ProjectsModel,
  })
```

In `ProjectsModel` I have an action that requires user property from root

```
const ProjectsModel = types
  .model({...})
  .actions((self) => ({
    loadStarred: flow(function* () {
      const u = getParent(self).user;      < here
      //....
```

I'm using TS and TS doesn't like it:

```
Property 'user' does not exist on type '(object & IStateTreeNode<IAnyComplexType>) | IStateTreeNode<IAnyStateTreeNode>'.
```

Okay I guess I need to type getParent?

```
const u = getParent<Instance<typeof RootStore>>(self).user;
```

oh no, it doesn't like it even more

```
'ProjectsModel' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
'RootStore' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
```

Where is the self-reference? How to properly type getParent?

Comment: Does this works for you? `const u = getParent<typeof RootStore>(self).user`

Comment: So did this help you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use `<typeof RootStore>` there:

```
import { types, getParent } from 'mobx-state-tree';

const ProjectsModel = types
  .model({
    something: types.string
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
    loadStarred: () => {
      const { user } = getParent<typeof RootStore>(self);

      // typed as User, no errors
      console.log(user?.name);
    }
  }));

const User = types.model({
  name: types.string
});

const RootStore = types.model({
  user: types.maybeNull(User),
  projects: ProjectsModel
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of circular references. One way of breaking this down and trying to skip the issue is

```
./root.ts
const RootStore = types
  .model({
    user: types.maybeNull(User),
    projects: ProjectsModel,
  })

./iRoot.ts
export type IRootStore = Instance<typeof RootStore>

./projects.ts
const ProjectsModel = types
  .model({...})
  .actions((self) => ({
    loadStarred: flow(function* () {
      const u = getParent<IRootStore>(self).user;      < here
      //....
```

There is also the approach of manually creating the interface like this:

```
./root.ts
const RootStore = types
  .model({
    user: types.maybeNull(User),
    projects: ProjectsModel,
  })

./type.ts
export interface IRootStore {    
  user: IUser | null,
  projects: IProjectsModel,
}

./projects.ts
const ProjectsModel = types
  .model({...})
  .actions((self) => ({
    loadStarred: flow(function* () {
      const u = getParent<IRootStore>(self).user;      < here
      //....
```

I don't like this approach becuase it requires the dev to keep the store & interface in sync.